# I have a problem in react native when i try to navigate to a material top tap navigation that contains a flatlist component

Tags: android, typescript, react-native, callstack

I have a initial screen in my app that contains a button to navigate to my home screen with the method navigation.navigate('HomeDrawerNavigator' as never), the HomeDrawerNavigator initial screen is my homescreen, but when I'm going to my home screen I have the following error:

Render error: cannot read property "getItem" of undefined
This call stack is not symbolicated. some features are unavailable such as viewing the function name or tapping to open files

[Error image on android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99dUC.png)

This is my drawer navigation that initial screen is my home screen

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export const HomeDrawerNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
        drawerPosition: 'right',
      }}
      drawerContent={props => <DrawerContent {...props} />}>
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="HomeScreen"
        options={{title: 'Home'}}
        component={HomeScreen}
      />

      <Drawer.Screen
        name="SettingsScreen"
        options={{title: 'Home'}}
        component={SettingsScreen}
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};
```

This is my home screen:

```
export const HomeScreen = ({navigation}: Props) => {
  return (
    <View style={{backgroundColor: 'white', flex: 1}}>
      <NavBar navigation={navigation} />

      <SelectAccount />

      <UserBalanceAndButtons />

      <AssetsTopTapNavigator />
    </View>
  );
};
```

When I comented the componetn AssetsTopTapNavigator the error is removed, but when I uncommented the error returns, this component have the material top tap navigation to navigate to a flatlist:

AssetsTopTapNavigator:

```
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

export const AssetsTopTapNavigator = () => {
  const {
    theme: {colors},
  } = useContext(ThemeContext);

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      sceneContainerStyle={{backgroundColor: colors.background}}
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarPressColor: '#72adfb',
        tabBarIndicatorStyle: {backgroundColor: '#72adfb'},
        tabBarStyle: {
          shadowColor: 'transparent',
          elevation: 0,
        },
      }}>
      {/* Display user tokens */}
      <Tab.Screen name="Tokens" component={TokensScreen} />

      {/* Display user transactions */}
      <Tab.Screen name="Transactions" component={TransactionsScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
```

The component TokensScreen and TransactionsScreen have the flatlist:

```
export const TokensScreen = () => {
  const {
    theme: {colors, currentTheme},
  } = useContext(ThemeContext);

  return (
    <View
      style={{backgroundColor: currentTheme === 'light' ? 'white' : '#323232'}}>
      <FlatList
        data={TokenItems}
        renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.symbol}</Text>}
        keyExtractor={token => token.symbol}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

I'm using "react-native": "0.71.7" with typescript

I would really appreciate if someone can help me

I have tried to follow this guide in the react native documentation (https://reactnative.dev/docs/symbolication) but I don't know if I am following it correctly because it seems to me that it is not clear with the steps that must be followed

Comment: Can you please show me some code

Answer (score 0):

My brother was able to solve the problem, the problem was that we were using a library that apparently works with classes in the components, and in the application we were not using classes in the components, so the solution is to tell react that only that library use those settings, and that is indicated in the babel.config.js file:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  overrides: [
    {
      test: './node_modules/ethers',
      plugins: [
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object',
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods'
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

In this file, react is told that only the ethers library (which was the library that was giving us the error) uses those plugins configurations, and that react native in general continues with the plugins configurations it had.

Comment: I'm running into the same cryptic error as you, and it seems like not many have encountered this. How were you able to figure out that it was the "ethers" package that was causing the issue in your case? And why is the property name "test:"?